# MySQL last value of day

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to construct a query that produces one value per day and I want that value to be the last recorded value of the day. This is what my table looks like (actual dataset contains a row for each minute):

```
+------------+----------+-------+
|    Date    |   Time   | Value |
+------------+----------+-------+
| 2015-06-14 | 13:00:00 |     3 |
| 2015-06-14 | 14:00:00 |     5 |
| 2015-06-15 | 11:00:00 |     6 |
| 2015-06-15 | 17:00:00 |     9 |
| 2015-06-16 | 09:00:00 |     2 |
| 2015-06-16 | 10:00:00 |     4 |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

I would like the outcome of the query to look like this:

```
+------------+----------+-------+
|    Date    |   Time   | Value |
+------------+----------+-------+
| 2015-06-14 | 14:00:00 |     5 |
| 2015-06-15 | 17:00:00 |     9 |
| 2015-06-16 | 10:00:00 |     4 |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

What would the SQL-statement need to be to retrieve this result? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.date,
       t1.time,
       t1.value
from table t1
where t1.time= (select max(t2.time) 
                  from table t2
                  where t2.date = t1.date);
```

Comment: Works perfectly - many thanks! Are these types of queries usually computation heavy and take time? For my dataset (~3000 rows) the query already takes more than 3secs. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: http://www.selikoff.net/2008/12/10/memo-avoid-nested-queries-in-mysql-at-all-costs/

Comment: Thank you - any idea how to avoid this type of nested query in order to enhance performance? Many thanks!